# I need the student with the most failed subjects based only on his last attmept to pass

Tags: sql, oracle

I have a list of a group of students, their subjects, grades and the amount of tries for each subject. The subjects repeat since some students try multiple times to pass. I need to select the student with most failed subjects but I cant count the repeated fails of a same subject, I need to keep in mind only the last attempt.

```
+-----------+---------------+-----------+-------------+
| [ name ]  |  [ subject ]  | [ grade ] | [ attempt ] |
+-----------+---------------+-----------+-------------+
| [ Peter ] | [ math ]      | [ 6 ]     | [ 1 ]       |
| [ Peter ] | [ math ]      | [ 7 ]     | [ 2 ]       |
| [Jessica] | [ chemistry ] | [ 8 ]     | [ 1 ]       |
| [Jesicca] | [ spanish ]   | [ 9 ]     | [ 1 ]       |
+-----------+---------------+-----------+-------------+
```

I tried selecting the failed subjects and group them by alumns but when I also try to include the last attempt, the result is only one subject with the last attempt instead of all the subjects per alumn.

```
Select 
    a.name, count(am.subject), am.attempt
from
    alumnos a, alumnos_materias am
where 
    a.i_alumn = am.i_alumn and
    (am.attempt = (select max(attempt)
                   from alumn_subject))
group by 
    a.name, am.attempt
having 
    am.i_subject = (select i_subject
                    from  alumn_subject
                    where grade < 7)
```

I need the student with the most failed subjects, not the most attempts failed.

Comment: You need to give more info. What's the schema and some examples. If possible get some example in http://sqlfiddle.com

Comment: [Bad habits to kick : using old-style JOINs](https://sqlblog.org/2009/10/08/bad-habits-to-kick-using-old-style-joins) - that old-style *comma-separated list of tables* style was replaced with the *proper* ANSI `JOIN` syntax in the ANSI-**92** SQL Standard (**more than 25 years** ago) and its use is discouraged

Answer (score 2):

How about using a HAVING clause to get those with failed subjects.

Then get the top 1 with most fails from that.

```
SELECT 
 a.name, 
 COUNT(fails.subject) AS total_failed_subjects
FROM 
(
   SELECT i_alumn, subject
   FROM  alumnos_materias
   GROUP BY i_alumn, subject
   HAVING MAX(grade) <= 6
) fails
JOIN alumnos a ON a.i_alumn = fails.i_alumn
GROUP BY a.i_alumn, a.name
ORDER BY COUNT(fails.subject) DESC
FETCH FIRST 1 ROWS ONLY;
```

A test on *db<>fiddle [here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=oracle_18&fiddle=b96dfc2a23eb53aed2ef1bb077c8cdad)*

But if you really need the last attempt?
Then you could use ROW_NUMBER to filter on that before counting the fails.

```
SELECT 
 a.name, 
 COUNT(fails.subject) AS total_failed_subjects
FROM 
(
   SELECT i_alumn, subject, grade, attempt,
   ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY i_alumn, subject ORDER BY attempt DESC) AS rn
   FROM  alumnos_materias
) fails
JOIN alumnos a ON a.i_alumn = fails.i_alumn
WHERE rn = 1 AND grade <= 6
GROUP BY a.i_alumn, a.name
ORDER BY COUNT(fails.subject) DESC
FETCH FIRST 1 ROWS ONLY;
```

Answer (score 0):

How about using conditional aggregation?  To get the students order by the number of fails

```
select a.name,
       count(distinct case when grade < 7 then subject end) as num_failed_subjects
from alumnos a join
     alumnos_materias am
     on a.i_alumn = am.i_alumn
group by a.name
order by num_failed_subjects desc;
```

Your question is a little vague on what you need:

- If you need just one student and have a recent version of Oracle, then use `fetch first 1 row only`.
- If you have an older version of Oracle, wrap this in a subquery and use `where rownum = 1`.
- If you need all students with the same number of fails, wrap this in a subquery and use `rank()` or `dense_rank()`.